# Which Maven bundle plugin should be used

Tags: bundle, maven-plugin, osgi-bundle

Which maven plugin to be used to generate OSGi bundle and how is bnd-maven-plugin different from maven-bundle-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maven-bundle-plugin` has been around for long time and that is why it most widely used.

`bnd-maven-plugin` was created not so long ago (mod 2015) to address some issues with `maven-bundle-plugin`. I suggest you read [Neil Bartlett's post](http://njbartlett.name/2015/03/27/announcing-bnd-maven-plugin.html) to understand the motivations.

The differences I'm aware of are:

- `maven-bundle-plugin` replaces maven's default jar plugin (that is why you need the artifact type to be `bundle` and not `jar`) while `bnd-maven-plugin` does not. The formar causes issues in some cases (with some other maven plugins). The later basically means the packaging is done twice (first by BND and then by maven jar plugin)
- `maven-bundle-plugin` can be configured directly in the `pom` or via `bnd` file. `bnd-maven-plugin` can only be configured via `bnd` file